# Proper response from nestjs with generated pdf

Tags: node.js, nestjs, jspdf

I am generating pdf with library `jsPDF`. My controller looks like this:

```js
  @Post('/')
  async generatePdf(
    @Res() response: Response,
  ) {
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.text('PDF with image', 10, 10);

    const imageData = readFileSync('src/pdf/template_1.png');
    doc.addImage(imageData, 'PNG', 0, 0, 100, 100);
    
    const pdf = doc.output();

    writeFileSync('/tmp/document.pdf', data, 'binary');

    const stream = new Readable();

    stream.push(pdf);
    stream.push(null);

    response.set({
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    });

    stream.pipe(response);
  }
```

I can save a pdf but it has no image. But pdf saved to `/tmp` has an image.

How properly to create response in nestjs controller?

Comment: @K J so I need add my image to response somehow?

Answer (score -1):

**You could start handling your controller:**

```
@Get('generate')
async generatePdf() {
  const generatePdf = await this.pdfServicesRepo.generatePdf(header);

  return {
    generatePdf,
    mensaje: 'Success',
  };
}
```

**And then create a service for the logic**

```
async generatePdf() {
  const doc = new jsPDF();

  const imgData = fs.readFileSync(
    join(__dirname, 'path'),
  );

doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 15, 10, 30, 30);

const fileName = 'file.pdf';
  const pathFile = join(
    __dirname,
    'path',
    pathFile,
  );
  fs.writeFileSync(pathFile, doc.output(), 'binary');
}
```